# How to make a good design and a normal app feeling (Material Design)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, material-design

I am making Apps with cordova, a programm which converts html, javascript and css code to an .apk file (i am only interested in android). Since about 1 year I am developing with this but I am not able to create an App which feels 'normal' for android and professional. **I want to make material Apps which feal like whatsapp.** All these little features like when holding a finger on a chat and it becomes darker, or waves which appear at buttons or the whole design at all.

Whatsapp is just an example of Material Design but how to make this with cordova? Near to every App(not games) on Android have that also 'little' Apps with 100 downloads are having often an material desgin where all these features are integrated. Also individual features which are only in one App work Material, how can they make it so good?

I know lots of examples of material design makers like http://materializecss.com/, https://material.google.com/,... where you can get javascript code to make SOME material design features, also its sometimes buggy which is not good. Also tried things on my one but its not the same like a 'Real Material desgin'. I know that you are not having as much possibilitys with html/javscript (cordova) as making an native java app for android but I think that it should be possible to integrate a Material feeling with all its features to an hybrid app.

How can you make Material Apps like Whatsapp with that fine tuning with cordova? How should you do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with JQuery Mobile. With JQuery Mobile your App looks and feels like a native app.

Take a look: https://jquerymobile.com/

For JQuery Mobile there a few themes available, or you can create your own theme. I think this is what you are looking for: http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/material/

Alternative to JQuery Mobile you can youse Frameworks like:

- Onsen
- Ionic
- Kendo UI

and so on...

Comment: thats nice but it isnt possible to do everything with it for example a caldender. This one is also an material object but you cant make it with jquery godesign...

Comment: also what is better onsen or ionic?